# An unhandled exception occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

```
int i=Convert.ToInt16(textbox1.Text);
Console.Write(i);
```

The above lines of code is showing the error `'System.FormatException'`. help me out.

Comment: Did you look up the exception?

Comment: I'm just wondering you're trying to convert a value from a textbox which is a Windows Form Control, but you're trying to output the value in a Console

Comment: i knowthat i have to use MessageBox.show() but then i want to convert this value in for someother purpose..

Answer (score 3):

This error means that your input string (`textbox1.Text`) is in the incorrect format. (ie, not a number)

Try using the [`Int16.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to handle errors appropriately:

```
short number;
bool result = Int16.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out number);
if (result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
else 
{
   // Handle error!
}
```

See [Why is this code throwing a FormatException?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4850304/1218281)

Comment: Tried TryParse as well, even the error exists it says tryParse takes 1 argument where in i have entered only one.

Comment: @BharathiAR I've added an example. Refer to the documentation for what arguments are needed.